# Sending values to a server to be stored in a database and recording space presses

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, events, key

I have two questions.

First: would this actually work? I'm trying to record every time someone presses and releases the space bar.

Second: if it works, what would I need to do next to get everything that is stored in RecordKey sent to a server to be stored on a database? (I already have mysql and php "up" and "running" ).

Thanks

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPressed, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyReleased, false);

var RecordKey=[];

function keyPressed(space) {
    if (space.charCode == "32") {
        RecordKey[space.keyCode] = true;
        }
}
function keyReleased(space) {
    RecordKey[space.keyCode] = false;
}
```

Comment: Create a database and use ajax calling a php script which insert/update data in database

Comment: @AkashKumar Could I possibly get an example, as in the code I would use here, with ajax that called the php script?

Comment: Anything missing? Why don't you choose best answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to send it to example server.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xv3d9rfj/

This is the function to send the data:

```
function sendToExampleServer(data_to_send){   
var x=new XMLHttpRequest
x.open('GET','http://httpbin.org/get?' + data_to_send)
x.send()
x.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(x.readyState==4)
        alert(x.responseText)
}
}
```

The function receives data to send, and send it to a server.
The are some issues with you code, but this is the complete code:

```
function sendToExampleServer(data_to_send){   
var x=new XMLHttpRequest
x.open('GET','http://httpbin.org/get?' + data_to_send)
x.send()
x.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(x.readyState==4)
        alert(x.responseText)
}
}

sendToExampleServer('up')


window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPressed, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyReleased, false);

var RecordKey=[];

function keyPressed(space) {
    if (space.charCode == "32") {
        RecordKey[space.keyCode] = true;
        sendToExampleServer('keyDown')
        }
}
function keyReleased(space) {
    RecordKey[space.keyCode] = false;
    sendToExampleServer('keyUp')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple ajax i am providing example for `POST` method you can also do it with `GET` method

```
function keyPressed(space) {
    if (space.charCode == "32") {


    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "recordKey.php", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){         
            var response = ajax.responseText;//recordKey.php response from echo function
            //console.log(response);

            }
            else{console.log(response);}
        }
    };
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "...";    
    ajax.send("key=B");//data you want to send like you do with GET/POST forms
}
        }
```

I am assuming you are probably new to this so i would recommend to you learn how ajax work. You can learn here http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

After that you can see here how to work with php and ajax http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp